# OSX Sonoma, MacBook Pro M1 Max: getting "could not connect to device" alert for Airplay from time to time

Tags: audio, airplay

I'm getting "could not connect to device" alert for a particular Airplay device, which works well from iPhone. Restarting MacBook fixes that. Restarting core audio services via `sudo killall coreaudiod` or similar commands doesn't (even though it does restart the service, evident by the audio stutter after command).

At the very least I'd like a way to just make "it" restart without restarting the Mac.

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Same. I have a MacBook Pro (M1 2020) running macos Sonoma. The device I am trying to connect to works, and connection to it from the iPhone using AirPlay works. Just, not with the MacBook. Also, the device shows up in the list even when it is not available on the same network.